# How to check for overlapping date ranges if one has null value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, date, ienumerable

So,

I have several cases that needs to be covered: I've managed to cover several of them but one case still remains mistery to me.

The acceptance criteria are:

1. there needs to be only one date with null value for end date (**checked**)
2. check if entered period already exists (valid from to valid to) (**checked**)
3. check if startdate is smaller than end date (**checked**)
4. check if entered period overlaps with null field for end date (**unchecked**)

Example:

I have first period like this:

```
period | start date | end date
first    2/1/2018      null
```

And I would like to validate this case as invalid because it overlaps with first case

```
period | start date | end date
second   11/16/2017    2/2/2018
```

Here is written code so far:

```
public (bool, string) IsValid(long someId, Numbers number, bool ignoreNumber = false)
{
    var reportQuery = QueryOver.Of<Numbers >()
        .Where(r => r.Some.ID == someId);
    var values = this.Find(reportQuery);

    // check if entered number already exists
    if (!ignoreNumber )
    {
        if(values.Any(x=>x.Number == number.Number && x.ID != number.ID))
        {
            return (false, General.ExistValidation.ToString());
        }
    }

    // check if entered valid from is empty
    var df = Convert.ToDateTime(number.ValidFrom);
    var dateFrom = df.ToShortDateString();
    if (dateFrom == "1/1/0001")
    {
        return (false, General.EnterValidFor.ToString());
    }

    // if there is already null value for end date then return validation error
    // only one null value for valid to can exist
    if(! number.EndDate.HasValue && values.Any(x => !x.EndDate.HasValue && x.ID != number.ID))
    {
        return (false, General.NumberValidFromValidation.ToString());
    }


    // check if entered period for number already exists (StarDate to EndDate) 
    if (number.StarDate .HasValue && values.Any(x => x.StarDate <= number.EndDate&& number.StarDate <= x.EndDate&& x.ID != number.ID))
    {
        return (false, General.NumberDatesValidation.ToString());
    }

    // this is not valid I want to return error if user enters values that overlaps with 
    if (number.StarDate .HasValue && values.Any(x=>x.EndDate== null && x.StarDate <= num.StarDate ))
    {

    }

    // check if stardate is greater than end date
    if (number.StarDate >= number.EndDate)
    {
        return (false, General.StageDatesCheck.ToString());
    }

    return (true, string.Empty);
}
```

Comment: *written code so far* -- So what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

So, if an end date is null, then it's effectively open-ended, correct?  If so, then all you really need to check for is whether a matching period has a first or end date after the start date of the entry without an end date.  Because anything after the start date would automatically collide.

Comment: Hmm,I don't follow...sry. Can u explain a bit more